Custom serializer for Jackson with togglebale options
I have a rather complicated Class structure that is needed to be serialized into CBOR. Now issue is that sometimes i need CBOR with tags while other times i need without tags.
Id like to be able to define the serilaizers only once and then have somesort of a toggle flag to tell the serialize if it should include tags or not.
I have
 private static final ObjectMapper CBOR_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper(new CBORFactory());

And it is used like this
CBOR_MAPPER.writeValueAsBytes(object)

Is there a way to somehow add additional options for spesific serialization calls?
